# No fields captured in BurpSuite

Tags: authentication, http, brute-force, proxy, burp-suite

I am using burpsuite to bruteforce my routers login form, but I have encountered an issue...

When I enter something into the password field, BurpSuite shows the request, but not what was entered. For example: (Username can't be changed, and I changed the `type="password"` to `type="text"`, so you can see)
Before logging in:
[image: Before logging in]

Burpsuite request (Notice there isnt anything to do with `foo` (what I entered as a password) in the proxy tab of BurpSuite)
[image: Request]

After logging in (and forwarding the request)
:[image: After logging in]

I was wondering if there is anyway to show the fileds, so that they can be bruteforced.

Thanks.